# Store checkbox value laravel

Tags: laravel

is_pilot is saving as 0, even when it's checked.

Store method

```
public function store(CounsellorAvailabilityRequest $request)
{

    $message = 'Availability added';
    request()->merge(['counsellor_id'=>auth()->user()->id]);
    $availability = CounsellorAvailability::create(request()->only('event_time', 'counsellor_id', 'is_pilot'));
    return redirect()->route('counsellor_availability.list')->withFlashSuccess($message);
}
```

view

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-checked" name="is_pilot" id="is_pilot"/>
```

any idea

Comment: I think you are missing `value="1"`

Comment: First you are assigning two ids to your checkbox field and second you are not assigning any value to the field.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `value="1"` is because if your `is_pilot` column data type is `int` and it won't allow any `string` or `boolean` value.

Without having `value="1"` your checkbox might send `true` as `boolean` when you mark as checked, and if is a `boolean` value then insert query will go with `0` value into database. So you need to add value in checkbox

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-checked" name="is_pilot" id="is_pilot" value="1"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-checked" name="is_pilot" id="is_pilot"/>
```

here the `value` attribute is missing, in absence of `value` the value we get on the server side is `on` or `off` which is not an integer that's why it is always `0`. Provide the `value` like:

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-checked" name="is_pilot" id="is_pilot" value="1"/>
```

and provide the unique `id` for every element and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Each item over an html page should have one id. Although this issue has nothing to do with your error but it should be corrected. Moreover every checkbox is assigned a value which is passed if a checkbox is checked. So your checbox field should look like following code.

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="is_pilot" id="is_pilot" value="1" />
```

Or

```
 <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-checked" name="is_pilot" value="1" />
```